# How to solve the problem with a particular "Boundary value condition"?

Tags: differential-equations, boundary-conditions

When I try to solve the boudary condition problem with the following code

```
Clear["Global`*"]
u = 0.1; v = 0.1; c1 = u (1 - 3 v)/(1 - 2 v); c2 = 
 u (1 - v)/(1 - 2 v); c3 = u (2 v)/(1 - 2 v); A = 0.6; B = 1.;
eqs = r''[R] + (c1/(c2*R) - R/(2 r[R]^2)) r'[R]^3 - 1/(2 R) r'[R] == 0;
bcs = {r'[A] == -A (c2/(c1*A^2 + c3*r[B]^2))^(1/2), 
   r'[B] == -B (c2/(c1*B^2 + c3*r[A]^2))^(1/2)};
NDSolve[Flatten@Join[{eqs, bcs}], r, {R, A, B}]
```

it appears the warnings of "Power::infy". Anyone can help explain this warning or solve this boudary condition problem?

Comment: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/workflow/UnderstandErrorMessages.html

Comment: Could you add the equation and the initial conditions in latex because I can see only a problem in the initial conditions, r[A] and r[B] are not defined